# Найти 2 элемента массива, сумма которых равна заданному числу

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, числа

Дан массив целых чисел, упорядоченный строго по возрастанию.

Дано некоторое число **X**, нужно менее чем за квадратное количество операций(то есть перебор всех пар) найти такие **два любых элемента массива**, что их **сумма равна X**, иначе вывести 0.

Как сделать это меньше, чем за квадратное время?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Решение за О(n):
Решаем методом "2 указателя"
Храним 2 индекса: первый сначала указывает на нулевой элемент, второй - на последний элемент.
Цикл - пока индексы не будут равны (то есть пока они не укажут на один и тот же элемент. Если такое случилось - значит, искомых элементов в массиве нет).
На каждой итерации цикла сравниваем текущую сумму (сумму элементов, на которые указывают индексы) с искомой. Если сумма меньше - увеличиваем первый индекс, если сумма больше - уменьшаем второй индекс. Если равна - решение найдено.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *a; // массив
    int n; // количество элементов в массиве
    int sum; // необходимая сумма
    ///
    //чтение массива
    cin >> n;
    a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    cin >> sum;
    ///
    // индексы
    int lt = 0; // первый, то есть левый
    int rt = n - 1; // второй, то есть правый
    while (lt != rt)
    {       
        int cursum = a[lt] + a[rt];
        if (cursum < sum)
            lt++;
        else if (cursum > sum)
            rt--;
        else // if (cursum == sum)
        {
            cout << "indexes: " << lt << " " << rt << endl;
            cout << "values: " << a[lt] << " " << a[rt] << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    cout << "not found" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как такой метод найдёт **все варианты пар?** Хотя в задаче ОП это, вроде бы, не требуется.

Comment: @Sergiks не "вроде бы", а не требуется. А если потребуется - при нахождении не выходить из программы, заменить "return 0" на "rt--; lt++; ", ну то есть продолжать поиск

Comment: Классный вариант.

Answer (score 10):

Поскольку массив отсортирован, то этим фактом можно воспользоваться для поиска второго элемента в паре с помощью бинарного поиска. Алгоритм следующий:

1. Проходим массив, для каждого элемента вычисляем, какая ему нужна
   пара
2. Ищем эту пару с помощью бинарного поиска
3. Если элемент нашелся и это не текущий элемент, то мы нашли пару

Т.о. получим алгоритм со сложностью O(nlogn): цикл дает O(n), бинарный поиск дает O(logn).

Примерный код:

```
bool found = false;

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    int first = array[i];
    int second = X - first; // искомый элемент
    int index = BinarySearch(array, second);
    if (index > -1 && index != i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} and {1}", i, index);
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!found)
{
    Console.WriteLine("No such pairs!");
}
```

Comment: да, согласен, но если изменить условие так: нельзя пользоваться сторонними алгоритмами; нельзя использовать коллекции или другие готовые реализации методов

Comment: @Lescott: Если это учебная задача, то не позорьтесь, прося нас решить её за вас.

Comment: Нет, это задача просто на оценку времени сложности, интересно было про разные подходы узнать)

Answer (score 3):

1. сосчитать необходимые дополнения до X для каждого элемента. Этой операциии не избежать. Получится убывающий ряд.
2. двигаемся по обоим рядам от меньших к большим, пока не находится равенство. Тогда пара найдена – значение и X минус значение.

Т.о. один раз пройти, вычисляя дополнения до X, и макс. 2 раза, разыскивая совпадения. И по результатам, исключить дубли зеркальных пар, как `(-3,15)` в примере ниже.

Недостаток – нужно хранилище для `2 x размер данных`. Это оптимизируется, но не будем усложнять.

**Пример:**

```
X = 12, исходный ряд: -3 1 3 4 7 9 12 15

-3 1  3 4 7 9 12 15

дополнения до X:
15 11 9 8 5 3 0 -3

двигаем пошагово указатель на текущий элемент в каждом ряду
от меньших к большим,
если бОльшее значение в одном ряду, в другом ряду берём следующее,
если равны, то для след. шага сравнения берём по след. значению в обоих
-3 1 3 4 7 8 12 15
-3 0 3 5 8 9 11 15

Находим -3, значит, пара (-3, 12 - -3 = 15);
второе совпадение (3, 12-3=9);
третье совпадение (15, 12-15=-3);
```

Надо ещё пройтись по результатам и убрать зеркальные дубли пар, если есть (тут один случай).

---

**Upd** не рассмотрел случай, если дополнение = значению и повтор одинаковых значений в исходном массиве, напр. `[1,3,3,4,4]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Цикл К=1 до N-1
  Цикл H=K+1 до N
    Если A[K]+A[H] = X Вывод A[K], A[H] Стоп

Если нет пар, Вывод 0
```

A - Массив

N - Количество элементов

Тогда через бинарный поиск

```
Цикл К=1 до N-1
  M = X - A[K]
  Бинарный поиск М
    Если A[K]+М = X Вывод A[K], М Стоп

Если нет пар, Вывод 0
```

в бинарном поиске операций меньше, около log2(n)

Comment: Ну получилось у Вас n(n-1)/2 - все равно O(N^2)

Comment: Да, именно!
я перепробовал варианты с нахождением  медианы, но это особо не помогло.