# Как сократить время выполнения задачи?

Tags: java, время, олимпиада

Решаю задачу. Решение правильное, тесты проходит, но вылетает по времени выполнения.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        byte s = sc.nextByte();
        byte l1 = sc.nextByte();
        byte r1 = sc.nextByte();
        byte l2 = sc.nextByte();
        byte r2 = sc.nextByte();

        byte ans[] = new byte[2];

        for (byte i = l1; i <=  r1; i++) {

            for(byte j = l2; j <= r2; j++) {
                if(i + j == s) {
                    ans[0] = i;
                    ans[1] = j;
                    System.out.println(ans[0] + " " + ans[1]);
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(-1);
    }
}
```

раньше использовал int вместо byte, но не помогло. Как можно уменьшить время выполнения?

Сама задача:

> Задано целое число s и два диапазона целых чисел от l1 до r1, и l2 до
>   r2. Вам необходимо найти два целых числа x1, x2 или определить, что
>   таких чисел не существует, для которых выполнено x1 + x2 = s. x1 из 1
>   промежутка. x2 - из второго.

Comment: https://coderbyte.com/algorithm/two-sum-problem

Comment: @cppquestions там язык слегка отличается

Comment: Важен не язык, а то что вы используете O(n^2) алгоритм, а в задаче подразумевается O(nlogn) или O(n). Вот ещё похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/460433/317064

Comment: @cppquestions если перепишу код на python, все выполнения можно уменьшить, даже с О(n^2)?

Comment: Сложность **алгоритма** не зависит от **языка программирования**. Ваш текущий алгоритм имеет сложность O(n^2), где n=max(r1-l1+1,r2-l2+1), потому что на каждой итерации внешнего цикла вы делаете ещё r2-l2+1 итераций. Существуют алгоритмы со сложностью O(nlogn) и O(n), которые я привёл по ссылкам. Если вы получаете TLE на Java, то для эквивалентного кода на Python почти наверное тоже его получите, потому что сложность алгоритмов одинаковая. Авторы тестов специально подбирают такие входные данные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я может чего-то недопонимаю, а зачем здесь вообще циклы?

```
int d  = s-l1-l2; // сколько не хватает до суммы, если взяли нижние границы
int d1 = r1-l1; // сколько можно ещё выжать из первого интервала
int d2 = r2-l2; // сколько можно ещё выжать из второго интервала
if (d < 0 || d > d1+d2) return "no solution";
if (d1 >= d) return "x1="+(s-l2)+" x2="+l2; // из второго по минимуму, из первого - недостающее
return "x1="+r1+" x2="+(s-r1); // из первого по максимуму, из второго - недостающее
```

Comment: чисел может быть несколько

Comment: каких чисел? Я понял задачу так, что задано два интервала [l1,r1] и [l2,r2]

Comment: ответ к задаче может быть не один

Comment: В условии не сказано найти все пары, и даже код в вопросе находит только первую пару. Но даже с этим условием полный перебор не требуется. После того, как нашли первую пару, остальные находятся простым инкрементом x1++, x2-- (или x1--, x2++) пока более короткий интервал не кончится.

Comment: дело давно было, будем считать, что код находит то, что вы искали)